# Audience Manager Contacts list

Tags: audience-manager

I am supposed to write a side windows application which reads records from some database and compares them with the contacts list in Audience Manager then synchronizes the Audience Manager by adding/editing/deleting the contacts.

I couldn't find any sample code on how to do that so I don't even know where to start from. I read that Tridion.OutbountEmail.ContentDelivery namespace contains the classes I need but... how do I connect to my Tridion installation? Which class gets the list?

I would be grateful for any hints on this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This kind of integration should be run on the Tridion Content Manager server, not Content Delivery. The API to use is `Tridion.AudienceManagement.API` and the documentation is available here: [API reference documentation downloads](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF.xml&docid=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF).

As to where to start, you can get a list of Contacts by calling `Contact.GetContacts()`, passing in a `ContactFilter` containing what you are looking for. The `parentItem` parameter can be left as `null` if you want all Contacts in the system. Note that you'll probably want to run your code as a Tridion administrator.